# Is it possible to change the mount point used for external USB devices from /media to something else under GNOME?

Tags: linux, gnome, mount, centos, automount

I'm using CentOS 5.x and am trying to change the mount point that get's used when I insert a USB thumb drive or external USB drive. They're showing up under /media/KINGSTON for example. I'd like to change this so that they show up under /external/KINGSTON for example.

If you must know my reasons for asking this, I have a domain where they're already using /media for something else and it would be more work to move this domain's automount from /media to something else. I'm trying to explore all my options before I decide on a path forward.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do this in [fstab](http://www.ehow.com/how_7200635_mount-usb-drive-fstab.html)

Comment: Iirc, it is hard-coded into gvfs.  Puppy had patches for Thunar, but not sure about Nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently not possible, the path used by GVFS is hardcoded directly in the source, so the only way to override it would be to fork GVFS, and make the changes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Edit you /etc/fstab file and add an line to it in this format

```
UUID=<UUID>  /external/<Name>  ntfs  rw,auto,users,noexec,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46  0  0
```

Assuming your pendrive is formatted as NTFS.

where  is the UUID of that partition and /media/ points to that directory
get the UUId by running

> sudo blkid

After saving the file, remount it using

> sudo mount -a

More references : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Comment: Read the question, **then** answer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams okay DONE ;p